# Error while use a keyboard made with js and ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

this is my first question in SO, i'll try to do my best.

I'm trying to put a keyboard into my rails application in order to allow users put some special characters with its search. Keyboard was made with JavaScript and the app runs with ROR. Everything works fine without the keyboard but once i put `name: "search"` which is necessary to allow js include characters in my text_field rails gets the follow error `NameError in QuestionsController#create`, however if i remove `name: "search"` from the view app runs fine but obviously i can not put any characters.

Here is my view

```
            <%= form_for(@question, role: "search", html: {class: "form-search", id:"searchform",name: "search1"}) do |f| %>
          <div class="input-group">
            <%= f.text_field :content,class: "form-control input-lg", name: "search", id: "autocomplete-dynamic", placeholder: "Escribe tu pregunta, ejemplo: ¿ Cuánto es 2+2 ?"%>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <% if current_user %>
                <%= f.submit "Preguntar", :class => "btn" %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'Preguntar',new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn' %>
              <% end %>
          </span>
          </div>
          <div class="keyboard">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
           </div>

          <div id="keyboard" class="wrap">
            <div class="content">
              <div id="first_row">
                <td><input type="button" value="±" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="∞" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="≠" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="∫" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="~" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="×" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="≈" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="÷" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="!" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="∝" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="<" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="≪" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value=">" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
              </div>
        <% end %>
```

my javascript:

```
function retornar(num){
var anterior = document.search1.search.value;
document.getElementById("autocomplete-dynamic").value=anterior+num;}
```

Question controller:

```
 class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :question_params


  def index
    @questions = current_user.questions
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.new(question_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Tu pregunta fue creada con exito.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Pregunta actualizada con exito.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(question).permit(:content , :answer, :user_id,)
    end
end
```

my application trace

```
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:72:in `question_params'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `_run__450535129__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__469022709__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

And my console

```
Completed 400 Bad Request in 49ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: ):
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:72:in `question_params'
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:27:in `create'


  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (34.7ms)


Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-09 15:02:25 -0500
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S3PJDzjKanM1wVmn76tZGmaIF6GcU6+crn3N6ijbB5Q=", "search"=>"dddd≥≥≥≅≅≅", "commit"=>"Preguntar"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `question' for #<QuestionsController:0xc29cc94>):
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:72:in `question_params'


  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (66.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

question_params method have two errors:

1. the name of param must be passed to require() method as a symbol (:question)
2. there are a leading comma after of the params.

So the fixed version of the method is this:

```
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:content, :answer, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but even with those fixes error keep being displayed, i think that problem should be in strong params.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. The whole problem was the js, and the view.

My refactored javascript

```
function retornar(num){
    var anterior = document.getElementById("autocomplete-dynamic").value;
    document.getElementById("autocomplete-dynamic").value=anterior+num;
}
```

and my brand new view

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="hero-box col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

            <%= form_for(@question, html: {class: "form-search"}) do |f| %>
              <div class="input-group">
                <%= f.text_field :content,class: "form-control input-lg", id: "autocomplete-dynamic", placeholder: "Escribe tu pregunta, ejemplo: ¿ Cuánto es 2+2 ?" %>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <% if current_user %>
                    <%= f.submit "Preguntar", :class => "btn" %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= link_to 'Preguntar',new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn' %>
                  <% end %>
              </span>
              </div>
            <% end %>

              <div class="keyboard">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
               </div>

              <div id="keyboard" class="wrap">
                <div class="content">
                  <div id="first_row">
                    <td><input type="button" value="±" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="∞" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="≠" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="∫" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="~" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="×" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="≈" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="÷" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="!" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="∝" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="<" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="≪" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value=">" onclick="retornar(value)"></td>
                  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the great support @guillermo